# Enviar imagen a servidor

Tags: php, c#, imagen, servidor

quisiera saber si alguien sabe como puedo enviar una imagen en base 64 a un servidor, actualmente lo hago de esta manera:

```
string imagen = "";
private static string Conversor(string Path)
        {
            byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Path);
            string base64ImageRepresentation = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);
            return base64ImageRepresentation;
        }


public void subirimagen()
        {
            imagen= Conversor(textEdit2.Text);
            string nombre = textEdit1.Text;
            string foto = textEdit2.Text;
            var client = new WebClient();
            var data = client.DownloadString("http://shopticul2020abcd.dx.am/HEIDI/CONSULTAS/HEIDIPC/subirimagen.php?foto="+foto+"&nombre="+nombre+"&imagen="+imagen);
        }
```

pero me arroja el siguiente error:

`System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (414) Request-URI Too Long.`

Me dice que la cadena es demasiado larga pero yo no se como acortar dicha cadena.
La razón por la que envió la imagen de esta forma es por que en el servidor tengo un archivo que recibe las variables y la imagen, este archivo se encarga de transformar la cadena de base 64 a una imagen nuevamente

El lenguaje de programación que estoy usando es C# y php 
Si alguien pudiera darme algún ejemplo o decirme que puedo hacer, se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: No termino de comprender, seguro que estas usando esos 2 lenguajes? en tu pregunta solo hay código de uno

Comment: Oh, es que el php lo uso en un documento que tengo subido al servidor, dicho documento se encarga de convertir la imagen en base 64 a una imagen normal de nuevo

Comment: Dudo que puedas subir una imagen por GET como un parámetro de la URL.Normalmente los ficheros se suben por post, y no como parámetro

Comment: Es que soy muy nuevo en esto y el único método que conozco